# How to develop a Task Manager Application

Tags: android

I Want to develop a Task Manager application in android. I am new in android application Development and I don't know how to develop it. Can anybody advice me or suggest me any tutorial for building a Task Manager application using Android?

Thanks

Comment: Specific questions are better

Comment: My suggestion: Start reading from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html). But you should also read [faq](stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) is for specific programming questions. My advice to you is to do independent research via Google, Android development books, videos, or other resources you come across. Then once you have a specific question come back here.

Answer (score 5):

There is a reference link available here:  http://android-task-manager.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/  and also this http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/android-taskmanager-simple-t315.html you will get idea how to develop Task manager in android.

**EDIT:**

First link has been expired but you can visit codebase on alternate [link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-task-manager/source/default/source?page=2)

Comment: First link is dead. Maybe this instead? https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-task-manager/source/default/source?page=2

Comment: @TamásBolvári Thank you so much for your contribution. I have updated answer as per your link.